# C login program that appends to csv file

Tags: c, csv

I'm trying to make a c login program that verifies whether the user input matches values on a csv file. If the user input matches values on the file, then the program will allow the user to login, otherwise, the user is redirected to an error HTML page.

The CSV file has a format like: Full Name,username,password. I'm having trouble trying to extract only the username and password to match adn ignore the full name. Can anyone give me some hints on how to get started?

Comment: Yes, read the CSV file into memory, then parse it into a struct array. Create a child process that can keypoll the stdin, and then pass the data back to the parent process via IPC for the parent to check against the struct's in memory.

Comment: Don't store passwords in plaintext. And SO is for specific programming questions; this almost always (and does here) require some code. And *don't store passwords in plaintext*.

Answer (score 2):

The CSV file format allows values to be placed in double quotes as follows:

REFERENCE: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

- Adjacent fields must be separated by a single comma. However, "CSV" formats 
  vary greatly in this choice of separator character. In particular, in locales 
  where the comma is used as a decimal separator, semicolon, TAB, or other 
  characters are used instead.

`1997,Ford,E350`

Any field may be quoted (that is, enclosed within double-quote characters). 
Some fields must be quoted, as specified in following rules.

`"1997","Ford","E350"`

Fields with embedded commas or double-quote characters must be quoted.

`1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"`

Each of the embedded double-quote characters must be represented by a pair 
of double-quote characters.

`1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"" truck"`

Fields with embedded line breaks MUST be quoted (however, many CSV 
implementations simply do not support this).

`1997,Ford,E350,"Go get one now
they are going fast"`

---

I wrote and used the following code to parse a CSV file with quotes.  I wrote and used `csv_getFieldN` to retrieve the **ZERO-BASED** NTH field on a line.
However, this code will NOT parse/ support a file with a field that breaks into the next line, even though that is a legal part of the CSV format defined on the WIKIPEDIA site.

```
#define  QUOTE_DBL_CHAR    '"'
#define  COMMA_CHAR        ','
#define  NULL_CHAR         0x00

/******************************************************************************
 * csv_countDQ()
 * 
 *****************************************************************************/
int csv_countDQ(char* data)
{
    unsigned int i;
    int          returnValue;
    if (data == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    returnValue = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++) {
        if (data[i] == QUOTE_DBL_CHAR) {
            returnValue = returnValue + 1;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
/******************************************************************************
 * csv_processQuotes()
 * 
 *****************************************************************************/
int csv_processQuotes(char* line, int* out_insideQuote, int start_insideQuote,
                      char* out_quoteData, int* out_quoteDataLen)
{
    int countDQ;
    int i;
    if ((line == NULL) || (out_insideQuote == NULL) || 
        (out_quoteData == NULL) || (out_quoteDataLen == NULL)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ((start_insideQuote != 0) && (start_insideQuote != 1)) {
        return -1;
    }
    countDQ = csv_countDQ(line);

    if ((countDQ % 2) == 1) {
        if (start_insideQuote == 0) {
            (*out_insideQuote)=1;
        }
        else {
            (*out_insideQuote)=0;
        }
    }

    (*out_quoteDataLen) = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < (countDQ / 2); i++) {
        out_quoteData[(*out_quoteDataLen)] = QUOTE_DBL_CHAR;
        (*out_quoteDataLen) = (*out_quoteDataLen) + 1;

    }
    out_quoteData[(*out_quoteDataLen)] = NULL_CHAR;
    return 0;

}

/******************************************************************************
 * csv_getNumFields()
 * 
 *****************************************************************************/
int csv_getNumFields(char* line) 
{
    int          currentIdxField;
    unsigned int i;
    int          insideQuote;
    int          NEW_insideQuote;
    int          consecutiveDQCount;
    int          result;
    char         quoteData[1024];
    int          quoteDataLen;

    /**************************************************************************
     * 
     *************************************************************************/
    if (line == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    currentIdxField   = 0;
    insideQuote       = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
        /**********************************************************************
         * 
         *********************************************************************/
        if (line[i] == QUOTE_DBL_CHAR) {
            consecutiveDQCount = csv_countDQ(&line[i]);
            result = csv_processQuotes(&line[i], &NEW_insideQuote, insideQuote,
                     quoteData, &quoteDataLen);
            insideQuote = NEW_insideQuote;


            if (consecutiveDQCount >= 1) {
                i = i + (consecutiveDQCount-1);
            }
            continue;
        }
        /**********************************************************************
         * 
         *********************************************************************/
        if ((line[i] == COMMA_CHAR) && (insideQuote == 0)) {
            currentIdxField = currentIdxField+1;
        }
    }

    return currentIdxField+1;

}
/******************************************************************************
 * csv_getFieldN()
 * 
 *****************************************************************************/
int csv_getFieldN(char* line, char* outField, int idxField)
{
    int          currentIdxField;
    unsigned int i;
    int          insideQuote;
    int          NEW_insideQuote;
    int          charIDX_outField;
    int          consecutiveDQCount;
    int          result;
    char         quoteData[1024];
    int          quoteDataLen;
    int          j;

    /**************************************************************************
     * 
     *************************************************************************/
    if (line == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    currentIdxField   = 0;
    insideQuote       = 0;
    charIDX_outField  = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
        /**********************************************************************
         * 
         *********************************************************************/
        if (line[i] == QUOTE_DBL_CHAR) {
            consecutiveDQCount = csv_countDQ(&line[i]);
            result = csv_processQuotes(&line[i], &NEW_insideQuote, insideQuote,
                     quoteData, &quoteDataLen);
            insideQuote = NEW_insideQuote;

            if (currentIdxField == idxField) {
                for (j = 0; j < quoteDataLen; j++) {
                    outField[charIDX_outField] = quoteData[j];
                    charIDX_outField = charIDX_outField + 1;
                }
            }
            if (consecutiveDQCount >= 1) {
                i = i + (consecutiveDQCount-1);
            }
            continue;
        }
        /**********************************************************************
         * 
         *********************************************************************/
        if ((line[i] == COMMA_CHAR) && (insideQuote == 0)) {
            currentIdxField = currentIdxField+1;
        }
        else {
            if (currentIdxField == idxField) {
                outField[charIDX_outField] = line[i];
                charIDX_outField = charIDX_outField + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    outField[charIDX_outField] = NULL_CHAR;
    return 0;
}
```